# My font wont load with font load async feels like i've tried everything

Tags: react-native, fonts, expo

I'm trying to add a custom font to my expo react native app and i've been having no luck

i'm trying to add a open sans font ttf file from google fonts that i have in a fonts folder which is in a assets folder and i think i'm linking it up fine because i'm not getting an error from es lint about unable to resolve path i also did react native link and i feel i wont through all the necessary steps provided online to add the font but being that i'm a real noob i'm hoping i'm just missing something obvious that a more experienced dev can point out this has been driving me crazy and i was even considering releasing my app with the default font

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, Text, TouchableWithoutFeedback } from 'react-native';
import * as Font from 'expo-font';
import { Checkbox, Provider as PaperProvider } from 'react-native-paper';
import EStyleSheet from 'react-native-extended-stylesheet';
import { widthPercentageToDP as wp, heightPercentageToDP as hp }
from 'react-native-responsive-screen';
import NumberInput from './src/components/NumberInput';

export default class App extends React.Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      checked: false,
    };
  }

async componentDidMount() {
        await Font.loadAsync({
          OpenSans: require('./assets/fonts/OpenSans-Regular.ttf')
        });

          this.setState({ fontLoaded: true });
      }
return (

     <PaperProvider>
     <View style={styles.container}>
     { this.state.fontLoaded !== true ? (
            <React.Fragment>
<View style={styles.inputs}>
     <View style={styles.inputText}>
     <Text style={styles.inputTextHeader}>1. Sold Price</Text>
     <Text style={styles.fieldDescription}>Sale price not including shipping charge</Text>
     </View>

     </View>
     </View>
</React.Fragment>
    ) : (<Text style={styles.inputText}>Loading... </Text>)
  }
      </View>
      </PaperProvider>
 );
 }
}

const styles = EStyleSheet.create({
inputTextHeader: {
  fontSize: hp('3%'),
  color: '#5D5D5D',
  paddingLeft: wp('4%'),
  fontFamily: 'OpenSans',

}
});
```

Comment: Search google for 'expo.font.loadasync not working'.

Comment: i've already done a lot of that that's why i'm asking here

Comment: Ok... I didn't criticize. I faced such a problem myself and it turned to be a bug (not solved yet) in expo.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, you should use a font function to add a custom font to the app 
by having a utility function

```
    import { Platform } from 'react-native';

    // generate styles for a font with given weight and style
    const fontMaker = (options = {}) => {
    const { weight, family } = Object.assign(
        {
        weight: null,
        family: Platform.OS === 'android' ? 'Roboto' : 'Roboto'
        },
        options
    );

    if (Platform.OS === 'android') {
        const suffix = weight === 'bold' ? 'Bold' : '';
        return {
        fontFamily: family + (suffix.length ? `-${suffix}` : ''),
        marginBottom: -5 // Font margin fixed for Android
        };
    }

    return {
        fontFamily: family,
        fontWeight: weight
    };
    };

    export default fontMaker;
```

Then use any font you want in styles

```
    import { StyleSheet } from "react-native";

    import fontMaker from "../../utils/fontMaker";

    const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    headerText: {
        ...fontMaker({family: "times roman"}),
        fontSize: 16,
        fontWeight: "normal",
        fontStyle: "normal",
        letterSpacing: 0,
        color: '#fff'
    }
    });

    export default styles;
```

Please follow the below tutorial for adding custom fonts 
https://blog.bam.tech/developper-news/add-a-custom-font-to-your-react-native-app

Comment: where should i place that function because i'm getting an error about only being able to place export in the top level btw i put it inside the render

Comment: To the question mentioned above, I would say use an import statement  

             import { StyleSheet } from "react-native";

        import fontMaker from "../../utils/fontMaker";

        const styles = StyleSheet.create({
        headerText: {
            ...fontMaker({family: "times roman"}),
            fontSize: 16,
            fontWeight: "normal",
            fontStyle: "normal",
            letterSpacing: 0,
            color: '#fff'
        }
        });

        export default styles;

Comment: so your saying that i make this function a component and then import it to my app

Comment: yes, a kind of utility function, also expo is always having this issue, fonts and other hardware issue are quite prominent, I don't use expo for this same reason.

Comment: i'm sorry im a real beginner can you spell it out in layman's term

Comment: and i already i imported stylesheet in my app are you saying to import it to the component

Comment: if you need I can help you out over a call

Comment: that would be amazing

Comment: try Using some other font

Answer (score 0):

I am a bit tired, so this could be silly but... shouldn't your if-else be reversed?

`{ this.state.fontLoaded !== true ? (<Text style={styles.inputText}>Loading... </Text>) : (Actual App Stuff) }`